# Can't migrate or makemigrations while trying to runserver

Tags: python, django, digital-ocean

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/apple/sanskar_handicrafts/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 425, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/apple/sanskar_handicrafts/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/apple/sanskar_handicrafts/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 373, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/apple/sanskar_handicrafts/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 412, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/home/apple/sanskar_handicrafts/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 438, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "/home/apple/sanskar_handicrafts/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 77, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/home/apple/sanskar_handicrafts/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/home/apple/sanskar_handicrafts/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/home/apple/sanskar_handicrafts/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 446, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/home/apple/sanskar_handicrafts/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/apple/sanskar_handicrafts/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 632, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/apple/sanskar_handicrafts/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/apple/sanskar_handicrafts/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 625, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/apple/sanskar_handicrafts/sanskar_handicrafts/urls.py", line 23, in <module>     
    path('', include('website.urls')),
  File "/home/apple/sanskar_handicrafts/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/apple/sanskar_handicrafts/website/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/home/apple/sanskar_handicrafts/website/views.py", line 12, in <module>
    for image in g_images:
  File "/home/apple/sanskar_handicrafts/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 280, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/apple/sanskar_handicrafts/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1354, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/home/apple/sanskar_handicrafts/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 51, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/home/apple/sanskar_handicrafts/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1202, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/apple/sanskar_handicrafts/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/apple/sanskar_handicrafts/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)        
  File "/home/apple/sanskar_handicrafts/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/apple/sanskar_handicrafts/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/apple/sanskar_handicrafts/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/apple/sanskar_handicrafts/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "website_gallery" does not exist
LINE 1: ...bsite_gallery"."id", "website_gallery"."img" FROM "website_g...
```

is the error I keep getting whenever I try to
runserver, makemigrations or migrate. Also when i run `SELECT * FROM table_name` for any table it tells me that it doesn't exist.

I've been following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BrVHwQ-SJUA&t=678s)
and this [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Stack overflow isn't really letting me post this because my post is 'too much code' so aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

Comment: Do you develop remotely on the droplet, or on your laptop? If the latter: have you issued a `git pull` on the droplet after you pushed the new commits to the GitHub repo?

Comment: @Dauros I develop through VS code and when I used `git pull`  this is what it told me `git pull <remote> <branch>` I'm not sure what to fill in for <remote>

Comment: How do you copy the edited files to the droplet then?

Comment: Nvm I figured it out, now the bigger problem is that when I try to use runserver it gives me an error saying `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "website_gallery" does not exist
LINE 1: ...bsite_gallery"."id", "website_gallery"."img" FROM "website_g...`

Comment: Have you run the [migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/migrations/)?

Comment: @Dauros I funnily enough can't because whenever I try to migrate or makemigrations the same error pops up

Comment: Check your models. The error message is about a non-existing `website_gallery` relation between two models.

Comment: @Dauros They're there Here's my models.py `class Highlights(models.Model):
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='highlights/')

class Gallery(models.Model):
    img = models.ImageField()` Also I don't think it's an individual table's problem since when I try to run `SELECT * FROM table_name` for any table whatsoever it tells me the table does'nt exist.

Comment: Could you show the full error message?

Comment: @Dauros I think the error is too long to fit in a comment

Comment: Edit your question or open a new one.

Comment: @Dauros Hey I just edited the question can you please check it out now.

Comment: Ok, so I think you added the new model `Gallery` but after that you forgot to run `makemigrations` and `migrate` on the droplet. Then you added some code in `website/views.py` that tries to fetch `Gallery` models from the DB, but they are non-existing yet so Django gives an error. Try to comment out every code line in the view function, which uses the `Gallery` model, then create/run migrations.

Comment: @Dauros Hey BIG THANK YOU LIKE A MASSSIVE THANK YOU, IT WORKED!!!! But now what do i do?

Comment: You're welcome. Do you have a new migration issue or something? Or what do you mean?

Comment: @Dauros Can I uncomment all the gallery code in views now lol? Also can you post your comment as an answer as it worked BEAUTIFULLY

Comment: Yes, now you can use `Gallery` model in the view function, since the respective table is present in the database on the droplet. So every time you add a new model, you have to run migrations first. Later you can squash migrations if you wish (if you make many small modification during development and you try to clean up a little bit).

Comment: @Dauros Alright! Thanks again really saved me here :)

Comment: @Dauros Hey sorry to bother you again like this but  can you please check out the new question I posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have added a new model `Gallery` but after that you forgot to run `makemigrations` and `migrate` on the droplet. Then you added some code to a view function in `website/views.py` that tries to fetch `Gallery` models from the DB, but they are non-existing yet so Django gives the error.

To solve this issue, try to comment out every code line in the specific view function, which uses the `Gallery` model, then create/run migrations.

After that you can uncomment all the codes that use `Gallery` model, since the respective table is now present in the database, the query will be successful.